# Convert aspx to CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, bitmap, aspxgridview

How can i convert this to `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="300px" ImageUrl='<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("Image"))%>' />` to cshtml? Can someone give me a hand?

```
<img src='data:Image/png;base64,' + @Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Model.Image) alt="IMAGES" />
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL9F0.png)

[Car Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50bMz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Image property in your model then It should as simple as

```
<img src='data:Image/png;base64,' + @Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Model.Image) alt="IMAGES" />
```

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message='System.Collections.Generic.List<rentacarmadeira.Models.Cars>' does not contain a definition for 'Image'
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: Do you have a property in your Model class Cars??